# How to unzip more than one folder in a directory - wild card not working

Tags: ruby, wildcard, watir, unzip

I'm working in Ruby/Watir
I am downloading files from a website they come in .zip folder
I want to unzip those folders but i dont know the name of the downloaded folder so i decided to use the wildcard which isnt working

```
Zip::File.open('my/directory/*.zip') { |zip_file|
     zip_file.each { |f|
     f_path=File.join("fil_download", f.name)
     FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
     zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The "wildcard" is actually a feature called [*glob pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). Ruby supports that trough [`Dir.glob()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).

It should be:

```
Dir.glob('my/directory/*.zip') { |filename|
    Zip::File.open(filename) { |zip_file|
        zip_file.each { |f|
            f_path=File.join("fil_download", f.name)
            FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
            zip_file.extract(f, f_path) unless File.exist?(f_path)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot more sense! Thank you so much!

Comment: That's a different thing, and not directly supported by `Zip::File`. You need to concatenate them afterwards. Or call a shell command. `unzip` on UNIX can for example extract to stdout. You might redirect that to a file. I suggest to investigate a bit and if you should not find a solution, ask a new question dedicated to that.